# errorDescription":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

When I hit the aff.lycafly.com, I am not getting right response.

Below are the exception arises in the code.

> {"Time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","errorInfo":[{"errorDescription":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}]}
> io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath@58b71ceb

My code:

```
String trustStorePath="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_172\\lib\\security\\cacerts";

String keyStorePath="C:\\Users\\saileshpraveen.vs\\eclipse-workspace\\com.web.api.automation\\Cert.cer";

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",trustStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",keyStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS"); 

RestAssured.keyStore("C:\\Users\\saileshpraveen.vs\\eclipse-workspace\\com.web.api.automation\\Cert.cer", "changeit");
RestAssured.trustStore("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_172\\lib\\security\\cacerts", "changeit"); 

RestAssured.baseURI= "https://aff.lycafly.com";

String response=given().
        log()
        .all()
        .header("Authorization-Basic:","0b017b0c0d414e20ee0d2e4adbed686d73ee67d3887ce1f9903c48bd3fc7693bee1d83e6cf87b53c")
        .header("Content-Type","application/json")
        
        
        .config(RestAssuredConfig.config()
                        
        .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                
        .setParam("http.connection.timeout", 1000)))
                    
        .body(prodflightpagepayload.ProdFlightAffLycaflyPayload.FlightAffLycaflyPayload())
        
        .when()
        
        .post("/Affiliate/Flight/Aw_SearchFlight")
    
        .then().
        
        assertThat()
        
        .statusCode(200)
        
        .extract()
        
        .response().asString();
            
        System.out.println(response);
        
        JsonPath js=ReUsableMethods.rawToJson(response);
        
        System.out.println(js);
```

I believe some goes wrong on my code.

Comment: This is the response from aff.lycafly.com, not from RA. You can double check this api with other tools.

Comment: Using the postman extension via chrome. request & response has been successful. How I integrate the response that I get from the postman extension that need to get through my rest assured framework java code?

Comment: This is the latest error I have got "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Why don't you provide the postman settings (screenshot) that make request success? It's helpful to find out what's wrong in your RA code.

Comment: Help me to get me the postman setting. Where we find that? Please educate.